# Ignore uri segments

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to be able to add the first uri segment which is 'admin' to my list ignore list but It is not working. It works with uri segment 2 & 3 but not with 'admin' is uri segment 1.

How can I make it ignore uri segment 1 'admin' as well

I use codeigniter 3 and HMVC

`$route['admin'] = "admin/common/login/index";`

**Core/Controller.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Controller extends MX_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $url = $this->uri->segment(2).'/'.$this->uri->segment(3);

    if (isset($url)) {
        $route = '';

        $part = explode('/', $url);

        if (isset($part[0])) {
            $route .= $part[0];
        }

        if (isset($part[1])) {
            $route .= '/' . $part[1];
        }

        $ignore = array(
            'common/dashboard',
            'common/login',  // renamed admin in routes.php
            'common/logout',
            'common/forgotten',
            'common/reset',
            'error/not_found',
            'error/permission'
        );

        if (!in_array($route, $ignore, $this->uri->segment(1)) && !$this->permission()) {
            redirect('admin/permission');
        }
    }
}

public function permission() {
    $path = $this->uri->segment(2).'/'.$this->uri->segment(3);
    return in_array($path, $this->session->userdata('access'));
}

}
```

Comment: So if I understand you want to take current uri and reconstruct it with 'admin' route removed?

Comment: Sorry still not clear what you want to achieve. You want to override the default routing for the 'admin' route and send like 'admin/common/login' to just 'login'?

Comment: Agree with @MikeMiller. Can you be more synthetic ? Like : I have this, I want that, I tried that.